# Angular4/Javascript Date changing after Date constructor call with timezone

Tags: javascript, angular, date

On my Angular 4 application I'm getting an date from my API call as '1990-03-31T23:00:00-06:00' string but when try to create a Date object and do getMonth() I'm getting the wrong day. After testing around in the console:

```
> var x = new Date('1990-03-31T23:00:00-06:00');
undefined
 > x
Sun Apr 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
> var x = new Date('1990-03-31T23:00:00');
Sat Mar 31 1990 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
> new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
360
```

and here's my code:

new Date(this.bsSelected.StatementDate).getMonth()

Not sure why this happening and how to avoid it. My temporary solution is to remove the TimeZone from the API output but I wonder if I understood the problem I could come up with a better solution.

Comment: The original timestamp is for UTC -0600, however the output string is for UTC -0500. "1990-03-31T23:00:00-06:00" and "Sun Apr 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT-0500" represent the same moment in time. It seems that your host is applying a daylight saving correction for that date and time (which it is required to do per EMCA-262). Also remember that months are zero indexed: March is 2 and April is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is being changed. `new Date('1990-03-31T23:00:00-06:00')` is valid ISO 8601 so will be parsed correctly by modern browsers (but not older ones).

"Sun Apr 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)" represents the same moment in time as "1990-03-31T23:00:00-06:00", but in a different timezone. Your host system settings seem to have daylight saving for that date (given that your current offset is -0600), hence the different time zone.

Recent versions of ECMA-262 require implementations to apply historic timezone changes, there have been many changes over the years so you can't assume that the current rules always applied (which is what some versions of ECMA-262 required).

> new Date().getTimezoneOffset()

Will return the host timezone offset for the current date and time, which may be different to the offset for a different date and time.

Why do you want to remove the timezone? The usual solution is to always use UTC and only use local values when presenting dates and times to users. There is not enough information on how you are using the date to know what will suit you best. Removing the timezone only works if everything should be in the same (host determined) timezone. Otherwise, you will run into issues.

And it will not solve having a different offset during daylight saving.

Note also that some browsers have parsing bugs (e.g. Safari), so removing the timezone (i.e. "1990-03-31T23:00:00") will mean that the string is treated as UTC, not local.

Comment: Very valid answer and points, my main problem was that my system was in -06:00 but every time I did anything related to Dates it was setting to -05:00. It's 12/07/2017 and it's not daylight savings in Chicago. I'm on Windows 10, after going to my time settings and triple checking that I'm in the correct time zone (UTC-06:00 Central Time) I realized there was a "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" switch. After turning that off the browser got my timezone correctly. I was simply trying to load that date from the API, and set the month and year on a drop down (index starting at 0).

Comment: Ok, but 31 March 1990 probably was during daylight saving, hence -0500. Daylight saving is based on administrative boundaries as well as time zones, so the location matters too (i.e. there are places in the same timezone where one observes daylight saving and the other doesn't, and also some that change in or out of DST at different times or dates).

Comment: Oh I didn't consider that even though the input came as CST (Central without daylight savings) Javascript/browser would "know" that 31 March 1990 was actually daylight savings and fix it. That explains it! Thanks for the help, this has been a confusing process.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Your browser is in different GMT that makes to become 1st of April.

I mean if in GMT-0600 is 31 March 1990 so in user's browser it's 01 April 1990

Try to remove offset part in string, browser will use that timestamp as current time.

check this one:

```js
console.log('With timezone:', new Date('1990-03-31T23:00:00-06:00').getMonth());

console.log('Without timezone:', new Date('1990-03-31T23:00:00').getMonth());
```

p.s. `getMonth()` returns number between 0 and 11

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript always converts to your local timezone when you use the Date object. If you don't need the timezone information you can do what you are already doing to strip it from the data.
If you need to preserve timezone information you can use a third part library like [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).